# Inherit prop-types when a component was rendered through props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Is there a way to inherit prop-types, when a component was rendered through parents prop? Assuming, we don't have access directly to 'ChildProps' and 'Props' interface?

**Parent component**

```js
interface ChildProps {
  counter: number;
  setCounter: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>;
}

interface Props {
  child: React.ElementType<ChildProps>;
}

function Parent({ child: Child }: Props) {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <Child counter={ counter } setCounter={ setCounter } />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Child component**

```js
function Child(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      // 'counter' is missing in props validation eslint(react/prop-types)
      <p>{ props.counter }</p>

      // 'setCounter' is missing in props validation eslint(react/prop-types)
      <button onClick={ () => props.setCounter(props.counter + 1) }>
        inc
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Since the `Child` really depeneds on the `Parent`'s properties anyway, why wouldn't you set the `prop-types` into the `Child`, not inherit it from above?

Comment: Just wondering, if it's possible not to write it by myself, but inherit from the parent. For example, if parent is an external module, and I cannot access to it's types

Answer (score 0):

Jack,

In React, you shouldn't really *extend* / *inherit* from classes other than `React.Component`, it's the only convention we follow in *React* to write components.

Functional composition is how we do abstractions with, like: writing a HOC to give certain kind of methods or properties to anyother component.

```
const withAdditionalProps = (someProps) => WrappedComponent => (
  class NewWrappedComponent extends React.Component {
    givenMethod = () => { /* some algorithm */ }

    render(){
      const newProps = { ...this.props, givenMethod: this.givenMethod  }
      return (
        <WrappedComponent {...newProps}>
          {this.props.children}
        </WrappedComponent>
      );
    };
  }
);
```

I hope that, or some of it make sense.

Comment: I mean only typescript's types for props, so I don't get that linting error `'counter' is missing in props validation`